# GameMaker Studio 2 - Path Not Found

Tags: game-engine, game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

I am using GameMaker Studio 2 to make a 2D platformer game. But when I tried to run the game I am encountering this error:
[It says: Path doesn't exists.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfC9q.jpg)

I don't even have a Z drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution! The problem is all about the subst.exe. 
If you don't know what subst.exe is: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUBST 

There are 2 steps to solve the problem:

1. You need to check Windows\System32 for subst.exe. If it is not there, copy it from a subfolder of winsxs. 

2. If it is there but still not working, check your "Path" from "Environment Variables". If there is no "%SystemRoot%\System32;" add it to its beginning.

3. Then restart GameMaker.